# How to force Google Street View to non-WebGL in the API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

We have a Google maps app with embedded Street View but lately it has been displaying black areas. I noticed that this issue does not happen on certain other machines and in IE browsers and worked out that it is WebGL causing the bug.

If I go into my Chrome or Firefox and disable the Graphics acceleration feature, then the bug goes away and Street View displays fine.

How to I get the API to force Street View to display in "Lite mode"?

[image]

Comment: I found a temporary workaround in forcing our app to use an older version of the API i.e.  `//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.28...`. If I set it to v=3.29, then the Street View bug reappears.